# an Integral of the gaussian

Tags: analysis

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-t^2} \left(-1+e^{\sqrt{t}}\right)}{2 t} \, dt$$

Please help me calculate this integral. in terms of series or other unclean solutions are fine.

Comment: $I\approx1.191683632722526761318584\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the $e^{\sqrt{t}}$ in its Maclaurin series and integrating term-by-term, Maple gets
$$ {\frac {\pi \,\sqrt {2}}{4\;\Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right) }}+\frac{
\sqrt {\pi }}{8}+\frac{\Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right)}{24} +{\frac {1}{96}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_4$}(1,1;\,5/4,3/2,7/4,2;\,{\frac {1}{256}})}}+{\frac {
\pi \,\sqrt {2}}{1920\,\Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right) }
{\mbox{$_2$F$_4$}(1,5/4;\,3/2,7/4,2,9/4;\,{\frac {1}{256}})}}+{\frac {
\sqrt {\pi }}{5760}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_4$}(1,3/2;\,7/4,2,9/4,5/2;\,{\frac {1}{256}})}}+{\frac {
\Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right) }{26880}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_4$}(1,7/4;\,2,9/4,5/2,11/4;\,{\frac {1}{256}})}}
$$
Is that unclean enough?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks!